# Read/ Write operations on .xlsx file

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

There is already saved .xlsx file into database from UI. now i am reading the data from database using below code and writing it temp location file.

```
    Dim Buffer() As Byte
    Dim Amount As Integer = 2000
    Dim TripCount As Integer = 0
    Dim reminder As Integer = 0

           ReDim Buffer(FileSize)
            TripCount = FileSize \ Amount
            reminder = FileSize Mod Amount

           If reminder > 0 Then
                TripCount = TripCount + 1
            End If
          For cnt As Integer = 0 To TripCount - 1

                Dim Offset As Integer = 1
                Offset = Offset + cnt * Amount

                Dim ReadCount As Integer = Amount
                If cnt = TripCount - 1 Then
                    ReadCount = CInt(FileSize) - (cnt * Amount)
                End If

                Dim b() As Byte = GetFileData(CLng(documentId), ReadCount, Offset) 'GetFileData methdo as last code segment

                Array.Copy(b, 0, Buffer, Offset - 1, b.Length)


            Next            

            Dim downloadFile As New FileInfo(selectedPath + "\" + FileName)

            Using bw As New BinaryWriter(downloadFile.OpenWrite)
                bw.Write(Buffer)
                bw.Close()
            End Using

Public Function GetFileData(ByVal documentId As Long, ByVal amount As Integer, ByVal offset As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim RetVal() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim b1 As Byte() = Nothing
    Try
        Dim sql As String = ""
        ReDim RetVal(amount)
        sql = "  SELECT  DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(F.DF_FILE," + amount.ToString + "," + offset.ToString + "   ) DATA"
        sql += " FROM table_name F"
        sql += " WHERE F.docid = " + documentId.ToString

        Dim data As DataTable = FetchData(sql)

        b1 = CType(data.Rows(0)("DATA"), Byte())
        Array.Copy(b1, 0, RetVal, 0, b1.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return RetVal
End Function
```

after getting file into temp location i am trying to open it but it's throwing below error.

Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsx' Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? if you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes

but same set of code is working for .xls format file.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? You seem to just be catching exceptions in `GetFileData` and throwing them away. Don't do that - just take out the `Try`/`Catch` for a start and let the exception propagate. If something has gone wrong you need to know about it.

Comment: Where does `TripCount` come from?

Comment: @Ben - now i have updated the code Ben.

Comment: Take the exception handler out of `GetFileData`. It may be masking the problem.

Comment: Also where does `FileSize` come from? Maybe that is wrong.

Comment: @Ben - FileSize is coming correctly as saved in database and GetFileData is also returning the correct data as per input data.
here after clicking on Yes button of information message
`excel found unreadable content in .xlsx...` showing the correct data as well. there is no loss of data.

Comment: If there is no loss of data (and you have verified this using e.g. WinDiff to compare the file you put in the DB with the file you got out of the DB) that means that the file was corrupt before it went in.

Comment: @Ben - i got the problem area and modified the code as answered below. now it's working as expected. thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the array size.

if file size is 2000 bytes. then

```
        Redim Buffer(FileSize)
```

after this Redim of Buffer array size will be 2000 + 1 = 2001

then after getting from database and putting into Buffer array and writing it into file as below.

```
        Dim downloadFile As New FileInfo(selectedPath + "\" + FileName)
        Using bw As New BinaryWriter(downloadFile.OpenWrite)
            bw.Write(Buffer)
            bw.Close()
        End Using
```

the file size is increased by 1 byte. in this case file size is 2001 bytes. so that it was showing the error.

now i have replaced the above with below and it's working perfectly.

```
         Using bw As New BinaryWriter(downloadFile.OpenWrite)   
             Dim newBuffer(((Buffer.Length) - 2)) As Byte
             Array.Copy(Buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, ((Buffer.Length) - 2))
             bw.Write(newBuffer)
             bw.Close()
         End Using
```

in above code i have declared another new array newBuffer and copying data from old array Buffer to new array newBuffer from 0 index to (length of old array - 2) to accomdate the size of file.